# how remove special character and digits from a string but ignore white spaces

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

i tried to remove special characters and numeric number from string of sentence but it should ignore white spaces if there is a more than one it should replace with one

SQL developer,oracle 11g

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE ('Annapurna1@ Poojari675&^','(\W|\d)','') from dual;
```

actually output is `AnnapurnaPoojari` but i need as `Annapurna Poojari`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can be more explicit about the characters you want to keep:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('Annapurna1@ Poojari675&^', '([^a-zA-Z ])', '')
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  alternatively use `[^[:alpha:] ]+` pattern to remove non-alphabetic characters and keep spaces :

```
select regexp_replace('Annapurna1@ Poojari675&^','[^[:alpha:] ]','') as "Result String"
  from dual;

Result String
-----------------
Annapurna Poojari
```

Comment: hi , can you explain how '+' is works here. i did not find any difference in output with and without plus . and also please tell how *,+,? uses in regexp_replace

Comment: hi @Annapurna + matches one or more occurrences, but in this case no need, you're right.